# How to remove fields from parent form?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form that I use to register users. I have another form that I use to login users. These two forms share common properties such as the username and password.

I tried to create a LoginForm that inherits from RegisterForm but I don't know how to remove fields I don't need for login, such as repeat password or the agree to T&Cs checkbox.

How can I do this? These forms inherit from Form not ModelForm.

Comment: It sounds like your inheritance should be switched around so that `RegisterForm` inherits from `LoginForm`.

Comment: Turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `LoginForm` is truly a subset of `RegisterForm`, you're probably better off reversing your inheritance.

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username = ...
    password = ...

class ReigsterForm(LoginForm):
    confirm_password = ...
```

Answer (score 6):

`del form.some_field` - either after instantiating the form class or in `__init__` (after the super call, and you'd use `self` instead of `form`).

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/specific_problems/#removing-fields-per-instance